# Aqueous Equivalent of the Michelson-Morley Experiment

Tags: special-relativity, interferometry

This question relates to the Michelson-Morley experiment and whether anyone has so far proposed an equivalent experiment using aqueous waves instead of optical waves. If it is true that

(i) The properties of optical waves and aqueous waves are ***approximately*** equivalent and

(ii) Nature is consistent in her implementation of traveling waves, then,

I believe such an experiment should manifest every characteristic of the Michelson-Morley experiment to some degree of ***approximation*** including relativistic effects such as relativity of simultaneity, lorentz contraction and time dilation.

Is this a valid assertion? If not,  why?

Answer (score 1):

> (i) The properties of optical waves and aqueous waves are ***approximately*** equivalent and
>
> (ii) Nature is consistent in her implementation of traveling waves, then,

You can make a good case that both of these are true.

> I believe such an experiment should manifest every characteristic of the Michelson-Morley experiment to some degree of approximation including relativistic effects such as relativity of simultaneity, lorentz contraction and time dilation.

This, however, is definitely false. The whole point of us needing to teach the Special Theory of Relativity is precisely that, if you did the experiment with water versus with light, the water case will see a shifting in the interference pattern, whereas the light case does not, even though it would be incredibly difficult to do, and somewhat difficult to define, what the appropriate water waves experiment should be.

The issue is that water waves really need the water medium to propagate. Light does not. That is a special property of light that other waves do not have. The only exception that shares this property with light, is gravitational waves.

So, even if optical waves and water waves are approximately equal, and Nature is consistent in Her implementation of waves, this particular fact causes the comparison to fail.